# how do i configure a certificate for caddy?

Tags: lets-encrypt, caddy

I understand that https is enabled by default and i think i managed to set up the caddyfile in a way that this is enabled: https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https

what i don't understand is how i configure the certificate to use. the documentation is very vague about that (https://caddyserver.com/docs/automatic-https), but i don't think caddy issues a valid let's encrypt certificate automatically.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is not possible. Caddy only supports self signed certificates.

Comment: Hi, it would be great to provide a link to official information that corroborates yours answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tls issuer` directive to specify how or from where the certificate should be obtained.

If you have obtained the certificate yourself, you can configure it like this in caddy:

`tls /etc/ssl/mycert-chain.pem /etc/ssl/mykey.pem`

You can also use the `tls load` directive to specify a folder with certificate and key bundle.

Here is the documentation on the `tls` directives: https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/tls